# css set left/right for first page in document

Tags: css, css-paged-media

Is there any way to set the current page to left or right in CSS? All I can find is `page-break-after: left/right`. The problem is that you can't do that for the first page in your document or it will start with a blank page!

Comment: Well, there is `page-break-before: left/right`, but I wouldn't know if that does what you're after. As those properties don't work in all browsers, I have always avoided them

Comment: That's close; it adds an extra blank page at the beginning of the document, though.

Comment: Also, left/right is supposed to be determined by language, but I can't get chrome to switch by setting the root element's language to Hebrew or Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page-break-before on your html element:

```
html { page-break-before: left }
```

See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#progression). IDK if Chrome supports this.

Comment: When I tried this it added an extra page before the element.